# Play Framework return result from Twitter Future

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a next code, this return true, when number is 0, otherwise exception

```
  import com.twitter.util.Future 

  def compute(x: Int): Future[Boolean] = {
     if (x == 0) {
       Future.value(true)
     } else {
       Future.value(new Exception("Invalid number"))
     }
  }
```

And my controller for work with this code:

```
 object MyController extends Controller {

   def get(x: Int) = Actrion {
     compute(x).flatMap {
       case x: Boolean => Ok(views.html.ok("ok"))
       case _ => NotFound 
     }
   }  
 }
```

but when i run this code, i get `type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.mvc.Result
 required: com.twitter.util.Future[?]`

How to extract value from `Future` and pass as result to response?

Answer (score 1):

Play uses Scala futures, not Twitter futures. If you have to use the Twitter future, you have to convert it. The following code is taken from an [Akka feature request](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2908-document-how-to-convert-twitter-futures-to-akka-scala-futures#/activity/ticket):

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Promise}
import com.twitter.util.{Future => TwitterFuture, Throw, Return}

def fromTwitter[A](twitterFuture: TwitterFuture[A]): Future[A] = {
  val promise = Promise[A]()
  twitterFuture respond {
    case Return(a) => promise success a
    case Throw(e) => promise failure e
  }
  promise.future
}
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
object MyController extends Controller {true
  def get(x: Int) = Action.async {
    fromTwitter(compute(x)).map { _ =>
      Ok(views.html.ok("ok")) 
    }.recover { case e =>
      NotFound
    }
  }  
}
```

Your case statement also doesn't make sense, a Future typed to Boolean will always result in Boolean. If the future fails, you can use `recover`, `recoverWith`, or `fallbackTo`.

Comment: It doesnt look like he would like to use Action.async. Just extract value from future

Answer (score -2):

According to [Future doc](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/#com.twitter.util.Future) error is caused simply because of flatMap definition. I would rather use `map` or `poll` method.

Moreover, I suggest using `scala.concurrent.Future` with Action.async like this:

```
def index = Action.async {
  val futureInt = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
  futureInt.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/ScalaAsync)